# Convert Time to decimal in C#

Tags: c#, time

what i need to do, is have two defined strings that is inputted by the user,

```
string in = "9:35"; //am
string out = "11:55"; //am
```

and i need to subtract them, so that would get the total hours that they were signed in. which should equal:

```
string total = "2:20"
```

then, i need to convert that into a decimal.. so, 2:20 would be

```
string decimal = "2.33";
```

I dont know how to do that, any help would be appreciated!

P.S: id also like to be able to calculate the total hours they were checked in from a decimal number, so basically the opposite

Comment: Be sure to use 24-hour time notation for times after noon.  Also, if the time span crosses midnight, or is longer than 24 hours, either the date will need to be included in the calculation or a more complex algorithm will have to take that into account.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("11:55");    
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("9:35");

double span = (dt1 - dt2).TotalHours;
```

Do you actually need the "2:20" or is that just an intermediate step?

Edit: If you wanted to go back, you'd just need to do a little bit of math. Take the remainder of the decimal and multiply by 60, then round. Those will be the minutes, so just add them to the hours.

Comment: I think you've reversed the two `DateTime`s; the span you'd get with this is negative.

Answer (score 16):

Or you could do like this:

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(TimeSpan.Parse("11:30").TotalHours);
// returns:  11.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, but its the first that comes up in Google when looking for ways to convert hours and minutes to decimal hours.

None of these answers work when dealing with more than 24 hours (eg, when dealing with hours in a pay period). I handled the conversion like this:

```
string HoursWorkedThisWeek = "50:08" 
//50 hours and 8 minutes
string[] a = HoursWorkedThisWeek.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//a[0] contains the hours, a[1] contains the minutes
decHours = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(a[0]) + (Convert.ToDecimal(a[1]) / 60), 2); 
//Result is 50.13
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
TimeSpan inTime = new TimeSpan(9, 35, 0); //or TimeSpan.Parse("9:35");
TimeSpan outTime = new TimeSpan(11, 55, 0); //or TimeSpan.Parse("11:55");

TimeSpan total = outTime - inTime;

decimal timevalue = total.Hours + (total.Minutes > 0 ? total.Minutes/60 : 0);

string totalString = timevalue.ToString();
```