# How do I convert current time to Decimal Hours?

Tags: c#, .net

From DateTime.Now, how can I convert the current time to Decimal Hours?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Time to decimal in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834271/convert-time-to-decimal-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, that would be the TotalHours property, which kinda suggests that you spent no time reading about the DateTime structure in the MSDn documentation.

EDIT: Actually, you'd get the TimeOfDay first, which is a TimeSpan, and then get the TotalHours of that.

Comment: sorry, but I see no such property in the documentation

Comment: Um, then you're looking at the wrong documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: your first sentence is worded in such a way that led me to believe TotalHours property is part of the DateTime structure which it is not.

Comment: Understandable, which is why I added the edit to my answer, which was added before your comment but perhaps you didn't see it.

Comment: Happy to help. Just leave the money on the fridge on the way out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using NumberFormat.DecimalSeparator.

```
DecimalFormat format=DecimalFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try these

```
Math.Round ((DateTime.Now.Minutes * 100)\60.0).ToString

double decimalTime = DateTime.Now.Hour + (double)DateTime.Now.Minute/60

Value = DateTime.Now.Hours +((DateTime.Now.Minutes + (DateTime.Now.Seconds/60))/60)
```

Comment: Or `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours`. Given that TimeOfDay is already a TimeSpan, there's no point creating a new one.