# How to get Total hours in c#, it could be more than 24hours

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, timestamp, timespan

I need **total** working hours in one month

`ex : 7:30 + 8:00 + 6:30 +9:30 its 31:30` i need answer as `31:30`
i tried with **TimeSpan**

```
 // create new timespan
  TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;

 // iterate through items
  foreach (var count in model.Items)
   {
      TimeSpan totalDonationSum = TimeSpan.Parse(count.Hours);
      total += totalDonationSum;
   }
```

I get the Total like 1.06:21:00 (if more than 24hours), I don't want like this

Let me help, if I am doing anything wrong or I'll do something different than this

Comment: Timespan has a TotalHours property.

Comment: how can i use, in above code? can you please help , I tried but get syntax error

Comment: I think you might want to convert the time in decimal, because 31:00 has no meaning in Datetime, see here how to convert to decimal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834271/convert-time-to-decimal-in-c-sharp/8755691

Comment: yes but if I get the total hours like 31:30 that would be 31.5 so it's difficult to understand the format to the end number of users

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong and yes, it can be done differently. Please refer to [mcve] and update question if you require more detailed answer.

Comment: TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse("7:30");
            TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse("8:00");
            TimeSpan ts3 = TimeSpan.Parse("6:30");
            TimeSpan ts4 = TimeSpan.Parse("9:30");

            TimeSpan total = ts1.Add(ts2).Add(ts3).Add(ts4);
            double totalhours = total.TotalHours;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you get hours and minutes separated:

```
// create new timespan
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;

// iterate through items
foreach (var count in model.Items)
{
    TimeSpan totalDonationSum = TimeSpan.Parse(count.Hours);
    total += totalDonationSum;
}

// calculate
int hours = (int)total.TotalHours;
int minutes = total.Minutes;

// display
string time = hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00");
```

Comment: in minutes if i get 02 then I get the only 2 as we take INT , any other alternative to getting value like 28:2 to 28:02

Comment: You can use integerValue.ToString("00"); then it will convert it with a leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Minutes to calculate, in the end format in Hours.

This code should help you:

```
int totalMinutes = 0;
foreach (var count in model.Items)
{
    DateTime totalDonationSum = DateTime.Parse(count.Hours);
    totalMinutes += (totalDonationSum.Hour*60) + totalDonationSum.Minute;
}

TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalMinutes);
string hoursFormatThatYouWant = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

//If you use a console or you can change for MessageBox or Alert :)
Console.WriteLine("Total Hours:" + hoursFormatThatYouWant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` property.

You can perform arithmetic operations with TimeSpans to get a `TimeSpan` as result and then get its `TotaHours` property like this

```
double totalHours = (TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(7)).TotalHours;
```

`totalHours` will have value of 31 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

by using the TimeSpan.Hours Property:

```cs
// Create a TimeSpan value with a large number of ticks. 
Console.Write("\n{0,-45}", "TimeSpan( 111222333444555 )"); 
ShowTimeSpanProperties(new TimeSpan(111222333444555));

Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}{1,8} {2,-18}{3,21:N3}", "Hours", interval.Hours, "TotalHours", interval.TotalHours);
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.hours?view=net-5.0

Comment: Please review the [help center guide on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)